# Characters limitation by Javascript function doesn't update the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have the following HTML code with JS script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function charLimit() {
        var TextAreaElements = document.getElementsByClassName("metaTextArea");
        var charLimitElements = document.getElementsByClassName("cLimit");
        for (var i = 0; i < charLimitElements.length; i++) {
          charLimitElements[i].value = "(" + TextAreaElements[i].value.length + "/" + TextAreaElements[i].maxLength + ")";
        }
      }
    </script>

    <textarea class="metaTextArea" maxlength="40" onkeyup="charLimit();">text1</textarea>
    <p class="cLimit"></p>
    <textarea class="metaTextArea" maxlength="100" onkeyup="charLimit();">text2</textarea>
    <p class="cLimit"></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to have a character limitation indicator near each textarea (by updating the text in the `<p>`s), but it simply doesn't do anything.

Can anyone indicate what goes wrong?

- This HTML is for a sidebar of a google docs add-on I'm building on google apps script.

Thank you

Comment: `charLimitElements` is a collection of `<p>` elements. A [paragraph (`<p>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) doesn't have a value. Use `.textContent` (or `.innerHTML`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `innerText` / `textContent` or `innerHTML` instead of `value` (if a `p` element can have a `value` attribute, there are no automated logic associated to its presence, and it does not affect the tag content):

```js
function charLimit() {
  var TextAreaElements = document.getElementsByClassName("metaTextArea");
  var charLimitElements = document.getElementsByClassName("cLimit");
  for (var i = 0; i < charLimitElements.length; i++) {
    charLimitElements[i].innerText = "(" + TextAreaElements[i].value.length + "/" + TextAreaElements[i].maxLength + ")";
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea class="metaTextArea" maxlength="40" onkeyup="charLimit();">text1</textarea>
<p class="cLimit"></p>
<textarea class="metaTextArea" maxlength="100" onkeyup="charLimit();">text2</textarea>
<p class="cLimit"></p>
```

However, I would personally not rely on the order of the elements to get the `p` associated to a `textearea`, but use an id. It would also allow to have each one updated independantly from the other. I also changed the name of the function, it's a good habit to have clear names so that people using your code can understand easily:

```js
function displayCharLimit(id) {
  var TextAreaElement = document.getElementById("metaTextArea_" + id);
  var charLimitElement = document.getElementById("cLimit_" + id);
  charLimitElement.innerText = "(" + TextAreaElement.value.length + "/" + TextAreaElement.maxLength + ")";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="metaTextArea_0" maxlength="40" onkeyup="displayCharLimit(0);">text1</textarea>
<p id="cLimit_0"></p>
<textarea id="metaTextArea_1" maxlength="100" onkeyup="displayCharLimit(1);">text2</textarea>
<p id="cLimit_1"></p>
```

Comment: in case the associated order works fine. Is there a reason that it will behave differently on future executions (in no changes are done to the code)?

Comment: @YanivAflalo with current JS implementations, the order is guaranteed, however, you'll notice that one can change the order of the elements through the developper console. This is a small change that adds more robustness to the code, one cannot guarantee future implementations in future browsers. And as I said, it allows each one to be updated independantly (so the code is not only more robust, but also more scalable, will not suffer performance issues if you use it with thousands of textareas)